# ArgumentCountError. Too few arguments to function App\Controllers\Kamar::hapus(), 0 passed CodeIgniter4

Tags: php, codeigniter

ArgumentCountError error pops up at my codeigniter 4, here's my view code :

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalHapus" id="btn-hapus" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-id="<?= $row['id']; ?>"> <i class="fa fa-trash-alt"></i> </button>

<div class="modal fade" id="modalHapus">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
    <form action="/kamar/hapus" method="post">
            <div class="modal-body">
                Apakah anda yakin ingin menghapus data ini?
                <input type="hidden" id="idKamar" name="idKamar" value="idKamar">
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Yakin</button>
            </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

My controller code

```
    public function hapus()
{
$model = new M_Kamar();

$id = $this->request->getPost('idKamar');
$model->hapus($id);

session()->setFlashdata('message', 'Dihapus!');
return redirect()->to('/kamar');
    
}
```

}

My method code :

```
public function hapus($id)
    {
    return $this->db->table('kamar')->delete(['id' => $id]);
    }
```

The delete function couldn't work
I might've also need to mention that i'm trying to delete a row
To give a better picture, i attach this screenshot of my project
[image]

Comment: Did you confirm that you are receiving the data in your controller by `exit('id is: ' . $id);` after `$id = $this->request->getPost('idKamar');`?

Comment: I haven't. what should I do to tell my controller to receive data ?

Comment: I recommend that you simplify your task and solve earliest concerns. Remove the session related code.  Just print some static text to see if the controller even gets executed.  If so, see if the post array is populated.

Answer (score 0):

the error message explains it actually: 0 arguments are passed to the function hapus() in your Controller:

> Too few arguments to function App\Controllers\Kamar::hapus(), 0 passed

This is an obvious result of the form action  in your view: `form action="/kamar/hapus"`, which doesn't send any ID as argument. You are using actually a hidden input field and send/receive ID as a $_POST variable.

there are 2 problems to resolve:

- change your controller function to just:

```
   public function hapus()
```

- The other problem is that this hidden input field has no value, so you need to populate it with the value you want:

```
<input type="hidden" id="idKamar" name="idKamar" value="the_id_you_want_to_delete">
```

Comment: I tried it, still couldn't make it work. The redirect works but it doesn't delete the data from the row

Comment: you still need to provide an id to delete, try static `<input type="hidden" id="idKamar" name="idKamar" value="101">`

Comment: How would if i need to delete the ID from ID database (auto increment), so i don't need to do it manually everytime i want to delete a row ?

Comment: Fixed it, thanks for the guidance.. appreciate it a lot
<input type="hidden" id="idKamar" name="idKamar" value="<?= $row['id']; ?>">

Comment: But there is another problem tho, with using this code <input type="hidden" id="idKamar" name="idKamar" value="<?= $row['id']; ?>". It always deletes only the last ID row. How can i solve this problem

Comment: You better ask a new question, as this is going beyond the original question, where you wanted to know how to delete ONE row. Anyway, you could create a form for each row, that should work, or use a javascript/jQuery clientside click event and detect the id and make an ajax-call to your controller.